# Html.ActionLink doesn't work in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, html.actionlink

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Account Page", "Index", new {
    controller = "Account", culture = (string)Session[culture],
    client = (string)Session[Client], brand = (string)Session[Brand],
    storeid = (string)Session[Store] })%>
```

This works in almost all browser (IE7/8, Mozilla, safari, chrome) except IE6. The problem here is the links are displayed as text.

How to get around with this? IE6 is one of the major requirement.

Comment: can you post the HTML output you're seeing in each browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying, but I found the problem. It wasn't the actionlink itself which was causing the problem. I had added a javascript (jquery.pngFix.js) for IE6 as a fix for the image and it was causing the problem. Once I removed this script everything worked. Again thanks for replying.